# Schematron regexp:test fails with broad expression

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, schematron

I am going nuts here..

The `test` fails using a broad match-anything regex like `'^.+$'` (shown in sample file) but works with a specific `'^C.+$'`

I also tried `test="string-length(.) &gt; 0"` and it fails.

Please help.

**This the XML file:**

```
<article>
<back><ack>
<title>Acknowledgements</title>
<p>The authors would like to thank <funding-source rid="sp1">CNPq</funding-source> (Process numbers <award-id rid="sp1">303287/2013-6</award-id> and <award-id rid="sp1">303559/2012-8</award-id>), <funding-source rid="sp2">FAPESP</funding-source> (Process number <award-id rid="sp2">2012/12207-6</award-id>) and <funding-source rid="sp3">CAPES</funding-source> (Process number <award-id rid="sp3">12357-13-8</award-id>) for the financial support.</p>
</ack></back></article>
```

**This is the schematron file that FAILS:**

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
        queryBinding="exslt"
        xml:lang="en">
  <ns uri="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" prefix="xlink"/>
  <ns uri="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions" prefix="regexp"/>
  <pattern id="funding_info">
    <title>Make sure funding-source does not happen inside p</title>

      <assert test="regexp:test(current(), '^.+$')">
          EC-CHECK: Nao deve haver 'funding-source' nem 'award-id' dentro de 'p'
      </assert>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
</schema>
```

**This is the schematron file that WORKS:**

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
        queryBinding="exslt"
        xml:lang="en">
  <ns uri="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" prefix="xlink"/>
  <ns uri="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions" prefix="regexp"/>
  <pattern id="funding_info">
    <title>Make sure funding-source does not happen inside p</title>

      <assert test="regexp:test(current(), '^C.+$')">
          EC-CHECK: Nao deve haver 'funding-source' nem 'award-id' dentro de 'p'
      </assert>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
</schema>
```

Comment: I _guess_ that in the first file `.` is discarding the newline. In second it's matching `C` and then moving on to `everything` since `.` follows `C` in regex.

Comment: I don't know much about `xml`, but if you are able to add `modes` then add mode `s`.

Comment: Try `^[\s\S]+$` or `^[^]+$`

Comment: Working or failing, if anything the first one should always work. If the second one works then it's not because of the apparent regex constructs, it's because of schematron's interpretation of it. Which of course is wrong.

Comment: You have not specified the context of the rule.  Also, could you please explain why are you using _exslt queryBinding_ instead of standar queryBinding and functions?

Comment: @noob the only mode allowed is i (case insensitive) and it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried both. The first `^[\s\S]+$` did not work. The second `^[^]+$` gave me an 'unexpected end of regular expression'. Thanks

Comment: Then, you should try `^[\\s\\S]+$`. In case it does not work, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @sergioFC I am using exslt because I need regex. If there's another way of matching different than regex:test and the `test="string-length(.) &gt; 0"` I will be happy to try it out..

Comment: THANKS @WiktorStribiżew `^[\\s\\S]+$` worked!! If you post it as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as correct! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the backslashes in the XSL can be used to define escape sequences. When you need to define a regex shorthand character class, you need to prepend specific characters with a *literal* backslash, thus, you need to use a *double* backslash:

```
^[\\s\\S]+$
```

This pattern will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\\s\\S]+` - one or more characters that are either whitespace or non-whitespace (thus, this matches any character)
- `$` - end of string.

This also means that the regex flavor is not JavaScript, althoug [this reference](http://exslt.org/regexp/) claims EXSLT uses JS flavor.